# scroll not working with keyboard appear

Tags: android, xml

i have their xml for activity i dont know wheres a problem when kebored appear scroll view don't work if change layout to relative then worked
 add this (android:windowSoftInputMode=stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan")
to manifest but still not working

here my xml 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzm3a327guxrgnn/xml.txt?dl=0

Comment: Post your XML layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScrollView anyname;
anyname =(ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sv_rl_user_settings);
anyname.setparentView.setOnTouchListener(this);



@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getactivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getactivity().getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;

        }
```

Hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently the ScrollView's `android:layout_height` mustn't be set to `wrap_content`. I set it to `match_parent` and set the `android:layout_above` to the button on the bottom of the page.

Or

Add below property in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: pleas  i seen this solution  but i don't  understand  it  can u  give me example or see above my xml

Comment: I have added another answer and hope this code will help you.

Comment: Please don't do this, use the edit function instead.